# Las data loading process with PDAL (Boundless tutorial)

Tags: xml, postgis, pipeline, pgadmin

I am following [this tutorial](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-lidar/) to load the lidar data into database. the order is create extensions:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION pointcloud;
CREATE EXTENSION pointcloud_postgis;
```

Look at the metadata:

```
pdal info --input 20090429_42122c8225_ld_p23.laz --schema pdal info --input 20090429_42122c8225_ld_p23.laz --metadata --xml
```

and run the data loading:

```
pdal pipeline laz2pg.xml
```

My pipeline is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pipeline version="1.0">
  <Writer type="drivers.pgpointcloud.writer">
    <Option name="connection">dbname=lidar user=postgres</Option>
    <Option name="table">medford</Option>
    <Option name="srid">4326</Option>
    <Filter type="filters.chipper">
      <Option name="capacity">400</Option>
      <Filter type="filters.cache">
        <Reader type="drivers.las.reader">
          <Option name="filename">20090429_42122c8225_ld_p23.laz</Option>
          <Option name="spatialreference">EPSG:4326</Option>
        </Reader>
      </Filter>
    </Filter>
  </Writer>
</Pipeline>
```

In this step I have an error message:

```
PDAL: laz2pg.xml: JSON pipeline: Unable to parse pipeline:

* Line 1, Column 1
  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.
```